# How can we change compression policy on timescaledb

Tags: compression, timescaledb

i am not able to use indexes on compressed chunks, so need to re configure compression policy so that at least 1 month data resides in hotchunks instead of 7 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to simply remove the current compression policy and create a new one with a new interval. Removing the policy won't decompress any chunks.

https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/compression/remove_compression_policy/

That aside, you can see all policies (compression, continuous aggregates, data retention, etc.) through the Jobs view, including the configuration for each job. Technically you can `alter_job` and update the configuration (stored as JSONB), but in most cases it's easier to just remove the policy and setup a new one with the appropriate `add...` API.